I'm trying to download file like pdf, csv which are store in s3 bucket. Downloading of this media is not working after deployment on amplify
When i'm adding the bucket link in anchor tag it showing access denied on deployment while getting downloaded locally. project is build on next 14
I have also update the rewrite and redirect in app setting project still not working
</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(pdf|csv|css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/> into /index.html

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
